# Magento events (including http_response_send_before) not launching observer with FPC activated

Tags: php, magento, events, observers, magento-fpc

I am making a full-observer module in order to change the store view depending on the user's navigator language. My main function is launched by the `<controller_action_predispatch>` event.

All work just fine without FPC activated. 
But once FPC has been enabled and has generated its cache, Magento does not go through controllers anymore (not on regular pages like product view, category view or home page for example). I did my research and found that the event `<http_response_send_before>` is always dispatched, even with FPC enabled. So I changed my previous event listener for this one, and it works well without FPC too.

Now the problem is that when FPC is activated, **the event is still dispatched correctly (made a log in the Mage function), but does not attach any observer to it.** I don't know how Magento initializes the `$_events` in App.php once FPC is enabled but it seems to be the core of the problem.
I have not found a single post about that on the internet, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. :

- I work on a Magento EE 1.14.0.1.
- I reproduced the same thing on a clean Magento of the same version, and the "problem" is present too.
- The cache was of course entirely flushed after I changed the observed
  event.
- This behavior occurred with the use of a custom event too.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across your post with exactly the same issue.

With Magento EE 1.14 FPC enabled, this event;

```
http_response_send_before
```

Fires a maximum of 2 times with a clean cache.  After that, it never fires again and/or the method you specify gets cached.  So after much testing of other events, I discovered that;

```
controller_action_predispatch
```

Consistently fires with FPC on.  Swap your observed event to this, and all should be right with the world.

Best,
Tom

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, as I said in my post, I tried this controller before trying `http_response_send_before`, which leaded me to ask the question here. I didn't have the occasion to rework that.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: have you tired controller_action_predispatch ?  that worked for us